# Rounding up/down predicitions for a binary outcome

Tags: prediction, deep-learning

I'm quite new to the subject of deeplearning and statistics, so please bear with me.
I was assigned to build a model that will try to predict the winner in a chess game.
Given a state of a chessboard, the model supposed to output the probability for a white player win.
So I'm using [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) to build that model, and so far it produces predictions.
Right now I'm using softmax output layer which produces two values: $[p\hspace{5pt}1-p]$, representing that black will win with probability $p$ and white will win with probability $1-p$.

My performance will be evaluated according to predictions I'm supposed to make on a test dataset; after I'm done training the model, I need to write my predictions for the test dataset to a file, `predictions.txt`, and this file will be compared against the true outcomes of the games. So, for example, if for a particular chessboard state my model predicted 0.82 and the true outcome is 1 (white wins), I will be penalized with 0.18 points. And if my model predicted 0.35 and the true outcome was 0 (black wins), then I will be penalized with 0.35 points, and so on.
My question is this:
Is this a good idea to round predictions that are 'very close' to 1 or 0? ('very close' refers to some bound that I will choose - for example: "round all probabilities above 0.85 to 1, and all probabilities below 0.15 to 0").
For example, suppose that the softmax unit in the output layer predicted $[0.07\hspace{5pt}0.93]$ (meaning, 0.07 for a black win, and 0.93 for a white win), is this a good idea to write 1 to `predictions.txt` instead of 0.93?
On one hand, It feels that I won't gain anything by doing so, since there's still 0.07 chance for a black win and I'm ignoring it, but on the other hand, It feels like the training dataset is not big enough to make the model predict a bit more "conclusive" predictions (Training dataset is of size 200,000 whereas the test dataset is of size 20,000).